# Is there a way to deliberately make a form field that doesn't submit?

Tags: forms, security, passwords, password-protection

A lot of folks on Stack Overflow are probably trying to fix forms that don't submit, but I'm actually hoping to do the opposite!

What I'd like to do for an art project is make a form with a "joke" field -- say, your SSN, your bank account number, your fingerprints or retina scans or DNA code, or something super personal like that. But I *don't* want the number in our server logs, and I *don't* want it to be transmitted over the internet at all. I don't want any legal liability!

Basically the idea is just to ask for something audacious, but *not* to handle the data that may or may not come from users who actually put it in.

So, is there a way to make a field that acts as a normal form field, but where nonetheless we would feel "safe" that users who actually do put their sensitive info in the field will be protected?

What's the "safest" approach to something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Form fields require a name to be submitted](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-the-form-data-set):

> 1. If any of the following conditions are met, then skip these substeps for this element:
>
>    - […]
>    - The *field* element is not an `input` element whose `type` attribute is in the Image Button state, and either the *field* element does not have a `name` attribute specified, or its `name` attribute's value is the empty string.
>    - […]

So you could simply use an `input` without `name` attribute:

```
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with your "jokes", if you want that the information of the field is not submitted, then, you can simply leave it out of the form element like this:

```
<form action="... >
    <input type="... >
</form>
<input type="... > <!-- This field won't be submitted-->
```